# Rash of trolling on SF&F, none of our mods are online

Tags: support, trolling

Someone is trolling SF&F pretty hard right now, and none of our mods seem to be around.  Can we get some CM assistance?

Comment: Can you drop links of post that needs handling in the [tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)

Comment: If you mean that "snarf" user it's just a troll, not spammer. Not saying he shouldn't  be nuked, but less critical than spam.

Comment: that snarf user has no posts anymore....

Comment: We have a CM on site now.  Thanks!

Comment: @rene - Jmac is dealing with it now.  The offending user's posts have been deleted.  All is well with the world.

Comment: I blame @Richard for going on holiday in Spain when he should have been wielding Mjolnir.  But then again, the policy on SF&F is "Always blame Richard".  It has always served us well.

Comment: The solution is usually "don't feed the troll." Your site won't break down over the course of a few hours if you just ignore the offending user.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In severe cases of spam and/or rude/offensive posts that needs a flagging mob you can drop links to posts that you want to be looked at in the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) chat room. Add some context what is going on so we can assess the situation correctly.

There usually is enough crowd present that have accounts across the network to flag posts. Beyond that they have the option to make the [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) go beep when the trolling user posts again.

This temporary flagging crowd can bring some relief until a moderator or CM is available.

Comment: Thanks, I will make a note of it in case this happens again.  If we hadn't recently had similar problems with a now-banned user and a series of sock puppet accounts, I wouldn't have said anything, but I thought it might be worthwhile to let the powers that be know what was going on.